# Python -- Filter rows from a file before calculations

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, average, nan

Next code calculates the average for each column in an input file. It works until the file has `nan` values which distort the average.

Here is my code:

```
with open(biasfile, 'r') as f:
    data = [map(float, line.split()) for line in f]

num_rows = len(data)
num_cols = len(data[0])

totals = num_cols * [0.0]

for line in data:
    for index in xrange(num_cols):
        totals[index] += line[index]

averages = [total / num_rows for total in totals]
print averages
```

This is a part of the file:

```
 22.7061 5.4303
 32.2040 5.4364
 22.9982 5.4426
 nan 5.4487
 nan 5.4548
 nan 5.4610
```

This is the output:

```
[nan, 3.1446607421875]
```

I want to ignore `nan` values and calculate the average of the rest values. How could I do this?

Comment: you should definetly checkout [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) and [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python list comprehensions to filter the data:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    data = [line.split() for line in file]
    data = [item for item in data if 'nan' not in item]
    data = [map(float, item) for item in data]

totals = len(data[0]) * [0.0]

for item in data:
    for k, n in enumerate(item):
        totals[k] += n

print([total / len(data) for total in totals])
```

Another approach:

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    data = [line.split() for line in file]
    data = [item for item in data if 'nan' not in item]
    data = [map(float, item) for item in data]

print([sum(d[k] for d in data) / len(data) for k in range(len(data[0]))])
```

Comment: how can i do if I want to add an other condition but only in the second column? For example when x>2 stop count and ignore the rest of the file?
@DanilSperansky

Comment: Ok, I solved this by putting a condition in the data and not in the average calculation!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the DataFrame API and do something like:

```
dataFrame.map(x => if (!x.isNaN) x).avg
```

Comment: Why so compliacted? [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) skips nan by default

Comment: Oh yes did not see that! Thanks